# How to match user's input without white space to array which has the element with white space in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Let's say I have `Table Tennis` in my array `[Table Tennis, Basketball, Swimming, ...]` and the user input is `tabletennis`, how can I make it so that it is a match?

This is what I have currently and `$q` is user input and `$skills` is my array:

```
if (preg_grep("/$q/i", $skills)){
    $skill = implode(" ", preg_grep("/$q/i", $skills));
    $searchRows[$key]['skills'] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="label label-info">' . $skill . '</a>';
}else{
    $searchRows[$key]['skills'] = count($skills) . ' skills';
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Compare user input to trimmed version of array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can go with a simpler solution?

```
    <?php
$testArray = array("Table Tennis", "Cooking", "Swimming"); //array to test
$testtoArray = array("tabletennis", "cooking", "swi mming");//array to test against
foreach($testArray as $arrVal)
{
    $arrValExploded = explode(" ", $arrVal);
    $var = "";
    for($i=0;$i<=(count($arrValExploded)-1);$i++)
    {
        $var = $var . lcfirst($arrValExploded[$i]);
    }
    if(in_array($var,$testtoArray))
    {
        echo $arrVal . "<br>"; //using this you can get the value from $testArray
        for($i=0;$i<count($testtoArray);$i++)
        {
            if($var == $testtoArray[$i])
            {
                echo $var . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$arrVal didn't match <br>";
    }
}

?>
```

This could work for any number of spaces.
Example :- "**This is a game**" match to "**thisisagame**".

Comment: I think this only works if the array only contains 1 item. If my array for example is [Table Tennis, Swimming, Basketball], even if I exploded it I still cannot match it because it does't know which one to match to.

Comment: @Blkc
Do you maybe have an array of all the correct values it should test against? Like `[tabletennis, swimming, basketball, someotherthing]` ?

Comment: Hi, and yes I have the array in something like [Table Tennis, Cooking, Basketball] to test against.

Comment: @Blkc
Code updated. Testing against an array is much easier.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I think you misunderstood. I need 1 word tested against a default array and return the word that is matched within the array.

Comment: @Blkc
So if `Table Tennis` matched `tabletennis` from the array, it should return `tabletennis` ?

Comment: Yes. so if `tabletennis` matched `Table Tennis` from the array, it should return `Table Tennis`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope, `strtolower ( string $string );` and `str_replace(' ', '', $string);` will help you.

**Example:**

```
$text = "Table Tennis s";    
$uinput = "tabletennis";    
$withoutwhitespace = str_replace(' ', '', $text);
$strarray = strtolower ($withoutwhitespace);
if($uinput == $strarray) {
  echo " Fine ";
} else {
  echo " Not Fine ";
}
```

Comment: trim() only deals with the start/end of the string. it does NOT work on the "middle" of the string.